# ActiveRecord query, order by association, last of has_many

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Im trying to list all *Users* by the `created_at` column of the most recently created associated recored (communications).

What I have so far:

```rb
User.includes(:communications).order(
  'communications.created_at IS NULL, communications.created_at asc'
)
```

As it is, `desc` works as I expect. The issue is when the order is reversed and I try order `asc`. It appears that is's because the *user* can have many *communications*, The query returns the list of *users* in order of the first communications created instead of the most recent.

How can I modify the query to target the most recently created associated records in both `asc` and `desc` order?

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Or you can cache the value in the user table, might be a little faster.

Comment: I'm hoping not to need to change the data model for something that should be well within the domain of a sql query.

Comment: It depends on your data size, performance requirements, and how often you need to sort.  Having all sortable attributes in a single record is the fastest way if that's needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem is you are trying to order the parent by child's attributes, so your solution will work only when their orders have the same direction.

The way to work with it is using aggregate function for the children's attribute like this:

```
# ascending
User
  .joins('LEFT JOIN communications ON communications.user_id = users.id')
  .group('users.id')
  .order('MAX(communications.created_at) ASC')

# descending
User
  .joins('LEFT JOIN communications ON communications.user_id = users.id')
  .group('users.id')
  .order('MAX(communications.created_at) DESC')
```

Comment: Thank you. That answered my question perfectly.