# ActiveRecord sort model on attribute of last has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've been digging around for this for awhile... I can't find a graceful solution. I have `loans` and `loans has_many :decisions`. `decisions` has an attribute that I care about, called `risk_rating`.

I'd like to sort `loans` based on the most recent decision (based on created_at, per usual), but by the `risk_rating`.

`Loan.includes(:decisions).references(:decisions).order('decisions.risk_rating DESC')` doesn't work...

I want loans... sorted by their most recent decision's risk_rating. This seems like it should be easier than it is.

I'm currently doing this outside of the database like this, but it's chewing up time and memory:

```
Loan.all.sort do |x,y| 
  x.decisions.last.try(:risk_rating).to_f <=> y.decisions.last.try(:risk_rating).to_f
end
```

---

I'd like to show the performance I'm getting with the proposed answer, along with an inaccuracy...

```
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report{ Loan.joins('LEFT JOIN decisions ON decisions.loan_id = loans.id').group('loans.id').order('MAX(decisions.risk_rating) DESC').limit(10).map{|l| l.decisions.last.try(:risk_rating)} }
end

    user     system      total        real
0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 ( 20.573096)

=> [0.936775, 0.934465, 0.932088, 0.922352, 0.921882, 0.794724, 0.919432, 0.918385, 0.916952, 0.914938]
```

The order isn't right. That `0.794724` is out of place.

To that extent... I'm only seeing one attribute in the proposed answer. I don't see the connection =/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveRecord query, order by association, last of has\_many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603949/activerecord-query-order-by-association-last-of-has-many)

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: We're using MySQL

Comment: @IlyaLavrov Doesn't matter if you abstract appropriately with Arel. ;)

Comment: @brendandeere can you describe how it pertains to my problem specifically? I can't seem to get the result set to match what i'm looking for.

Comment: @coreyward Not true. Different databases have different capabilities and limitations. AREL can't make a database do something it doesn't support (window functions for example).

Comment: @muistooshort This doesn't require window functions, and it's something Arel is quite capable of handling in a platform-independent way, but StackOverflow is all too happy to share inflexible answers with SQL literals mucking up an otherwise effective system.

Comment: @coreyward ... how about an answer? ;-)

Comment: @Dudo Alright, alright… answered. :)

Answer (score 2):

Alright, it looks like I'm working late tonight because I couldn't help but jump in:

```
class Loan < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :decisions
  has_one :latest_decision, -> { merge(Decision.latest) }, class_name: 'Decision'
end

class Decision < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :loan

  def latest
    t1 = arel_table
    t2 = arel_table.alias('t2')

    # Self join based on `loan_id` prefer latest `created_at`
    join_on = t1[:loan_id].eq(t2[:loan_id]).and(
      t1[:created_at].lt(t2[:created_at]))

    where(t2[:loan_id].eq(nil)).joins(
      t1.create_join(t2, t1.create_on(join_condition), Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin)
    )
  end
end

Loan.includes(:latest_decision)
```

This doesn't sort, just provides the latest decision for each loan. Throwing an `order` that references `access_codes` messes things up because of the table aliasing. I don't have the time to work that kink out now, but I bet you can figure it out if you check out some of the great resources on Arel and how to use it with ActiveRecord. I really enjoy [this one](http://danshultz.github.io/talks/mastering_activerecord_arel/).

Answer (score 1):

At first let's write sql-query which will select necessary data. SO contains a question which may helps here: [Select most recent row with GROUP BY in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688063/select-most-recent-row-with-group-by-in-mysql#16215861). My best version:

```
SELECT loans.*
FROM loans
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT loan_id, MAX(id) as id
  FROM decisions
  GROUP BY loan_id) d ON d.loan_id = loans.id
LEFT JOIN decisions ON decisions.id = d.id
ORDER BY decisions.risk_rating DESC
```

This code suppose `MAX(id)` gives `id` of the recent row in group.

You may do the same query by this Rails code:

```
sub_query = 
  Decision.select('loan_id, MAX(id) as id').
    group(:loan_id).to_sql

Loan.
  joins("LEFT JOIN (#{sub_query}) d ON d.loan_id = loans.id").
  joins("LEFT JOIN decisions ON decisions.id = d.id").
  order("decisions.risk_rating DESC")
```

Unfortunately, I don't have MySQL at hand and I can't try this code. Hope it will work.